# reversing every odd string and adding them together

Tags: java, string, math, split, reverse

i want to reverse every odd pair of strings and them add them together with the even pair.

for example the string 123456789 would turn into 213465789 and then adding them together would give 21+34+65+78+9 which = 207.

my current code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Num = "123456789";
    System.out.println(reverse(Num) + ".");
} 

public static int reverse(String a) {
    String newa = "";
    String revString = "";
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i=i+4) {
        newa = (a.substring(i, i + 2));
        ch = newa.charAt(i);
        revString = ch + revString;
       }
    }
```

I do have an general idea which is to reverse every second pair of strings and place them back into a new string that would be "213465789". Then split the string into pairs and add them up and whatever other operation like /, * and % but i cant seem to write my code

Thanks in advance

Comment: Voldermont Lord? Is that you?

Comment: @MarounMaroun : shhh...his name is not taken!! :\

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: i cant seem to write the code

Comment: Is the number of characters in the string guaranteed to be divisible by two?

Comment: @ Jason Lepack. there can be an odd number of characters in the string

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
int pairCout=0;
int sum =0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length();i+=2) {
        String newa = a.substring(i, (i + 2)<a.length()?(i+2):a.length());
        pairCout++;
        if(pairCout%2 ==0){     // EVEN/ODD separation
            String reverse = new StringBuilder(newa ).reverse().toString();
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(reverse); // SUMMATION
        }else{
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(newa );  // SUMMATION
        }
}
```

Just an approach - OUTPUT - 207

Answer (score 0):

Simply algo would be something like

- `String Num = "123456789";`
- Loop for(int i= 0 to n-3;i=i+2) - *to reverse the string*
- swap `i` with `i+1` - *this give alternate rev string*
- again `for(int i= 0 to n-3;i=i+2)` - *to add the sum*
- `sum = sum + ((chatAt(i)-'0')*10+(charAt(i+1)-'0'))` - *typecast from `char` to `int` using `[char]-'0'` logic*, for String "21", logic would be to have (2*10+1)

Comment: Bettoer use `Integer.parse` to convert from string to int

Comment: @talex : agreed...but i am more of old school type..plus this method doesn't do any harm in terms of performance IMHO!! :)